# test are skipped when running via batch file but are executing on eclipse ide

Tags: java, testng, classpath, web-api-testing

Test are getting skipped when run via batch file on command line but these test are executing on eclipse ide

I am writing java code for API testing using RestAssured framework and I want to execute script through a batch file on the command line but currently, my tests are skipped on the command line but are properly executing on eclipse ide

```
set classpath=C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\bin;C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\lib\*;C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\lib\Rest-Assured_jar_files\rest-assured-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\lib\Rest-Assured_jar_files\groovy-2.4.6;C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\lib\Rest-Assured_jar_files\rest-assured-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\lib\Rest-Assured_jar_files\groovy-json-2.4.6;C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\lib\Rest-Assured_jar_files\groovy-xml-2.4.6;C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\lib\Rest-Assured_jar_files\groovy-all-2.4.16.jar
java org.testng.TestNG -log 10 C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\testng.xml
pause



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="API_Automation.ApiOperationsTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

so that was my batch file and testng.xml file
By editing XML file for getting description for test skipped i got to know that my test are throwing an exception while running code through the command line
following are the exceptions-

```
[TestNG] RUNNING: Suite: "Test" containing "1" Tests (config: C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\testng.xml)
[TestNG] INVOKING CONFIGURATION: "Test" - @BeforeTest API_Automation.ApiOperationsTest.StartDriver()
[TestNG] FAILED CONFIGURATION: "Test" - @BeforeTest API_Automation.ApiOperationsTest.StartDriver() finished in 1245 ms
[TestNG] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
[TestNG]        at io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig.defaultHttpClientFactory(HttpClientConfig.java:264)
[TestNG]        at io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig.<init>(HttpClientConfig.java:76)
[TestNG]        at io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.<init>(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
[TestNG]        at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:420)
[TestNG]        at API_Automation.ApiOperationsTest.StartDriver(ApiOperationsTest.java:36)
[TestNG]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[TestNG]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[TestNG]        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[TestNG]        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1442)
[TestNG]        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1411)
[TestNG] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[TestNG]        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[TestNG]        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[TestNG]        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[TestNG]        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[TestNG]        ... 27 more
[TestNG] SKIPPED: "Test" - API_Automation.ApiOperationsTest.CompleteFlow() finished in 0 ms
```

For one thing, I am sure that program is unable to fetch jar files on runtime from lib folder.
And if i mention the path of the particular jar file in Classpath than that file Exception is resolved.

**Why Program is unable to fetch jar files at runtime in lib folder.Why is it only accessing those jar files, of which direct path is mentioned on Classpath?**

Comment: could you update your question with example of batch file. how are you executing tests from command line?

Comment: I have added batch file commands above in the code section. I am keeping all the files including jar files and the batch file in the same project folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpath your batch file is setting probably doesn't contain the library from which `HttpClient` (the class that is not found) is supposed to be taken, while the project configuration in the IDE does have that library in its classpath so it works from the IDE.

To verify that this is the case, add in your test a statement to print out the current classpath and see if it's the same when you run from the IDE: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))`

If that is the case, you need to modify the setting of the classpath in your batch file, adding to it the path where the library with the missing classes is.

Comment: I have checked classpath, from the Config statement printed on terminal:

[TestNG] RUNNING: Suite: "Test" containing "1" Tests (config: C:\Users\Daffolap-624\workspace\WapandaParallel1\testng.xml)
It is the same path that IDE is picking.My issue is that the classpath of jarfiles which i am explicitly adding in batch files are only not giving exception when run via terminal else one after the other jar files are throwing same exception.

Comment: "C:\.... \testng.xml" is not the classpath. My advice is to figure out what JAR contains the class not found, and set the classpath such that it contains that JAR.

Comment: Classpath was not taking jar files so I have modified the classpath and my issue is resolved..@SantiBailors: Thanks for the response!